# Static and Instance methods with the same name?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have a class with both a static and a non-static interface in C#. Is it possible to have a static and a non-static method in a class with the same name and signature?

I get a compiler error when I try to do this, but for some reason I thought there was a way to do this. Am I wrong or is there no way to have both static and non-static methods in the same class?

If this is not possible, is there a good way to implement something like this that can be applied generically to any situation?

**EDIT**
From the responses I've received, it's clear that there is no way to do this. I'm going with a different naming system to work around this problem.

Comment: Can you provide an example of where you might want to do this?

Comment: I don't recommend that you rely on case differences to distinguish two methods. Really bad idea. You should never have two methods that differ only in case: I guarantee that you will end up calling the wrong one.

Comment: Rename the methods to different names. Relying on case is not safe, especially if there is ever a chance the compiled code will be used by another .NET language that isn't case sensitive. Just because the language is case sensitive you should rely on that fact to disambiguate method names.

Comment: This code will only ever by compiled in C#. My company uses C# exclusively and there is no chance the code will ever be converted or used in another language, so I'm safe in this case.

Comment: Knowing the difference between Ball vs BaII, or LOOP vs L00P is one thing and already causes enough trouble, knowing the difference between doSomething vs DoSomething makes it really tricky, and before you know it, you find yourself commenting each case to make it clear for other programmers, or yourself when you look again at it next week.

Comment: For the record, you can't do it using extension methods to take the place of the non-static interface.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

No you can't. The reason for the limitation is that static methods can also be called from non-static contexts without needing to prepend the class name (so MyStaticMethod() instead of MyClass.MyStaticMethod()).  The compiler can't tell which you're looking for if you have both.

You can have static and non-static methods with the same name, but different parameters following the same rules as method overloading, they just can't have exactly the same signature.

Comment: I find the logic of this answer flawed. I see no reason why C# couldn't perform disambiguation by requiring the "this." token to call the instance method in this situation. Plus, andasa show a way that static and instance methods can have the same name.

Comment: True, they could probably do some type of checking which would select the static method by default if there was a collision, and require this. for accessing the instance methods. Of course that would become tricky when dealing with static properties, since within the scope of a method if your parameters were named the same as one of your static/instance properties then you would then have to use the classname to specify the static version, this to specify the instance version, and if there is nothing, access the parameter. Sounds like an excellent way to get lots of hard to find bugs to me.

Comment: I think all calls from a non-static scope should be made to the non-static method by default.  If you want the global then you should ask for it by prefixing with the class name.

Answer (score 63):

Actually, there kind of is a way to accomplish this by explicitly implementing an interface. It is not a perfect solution but it can work in some cases.

```
interface IFoo
{
    void Bar();
}

class Foo : IFoo
{
    static void Bar()
    {
    }

    void IFoo.Bar()
    {
        Bar();
    }
}
```

I sometimes run into this situation when I make wrapper classes for P/Invoke calls.

Comment: My exact reasoning for doing this was P/Invoke calls. Thanks :)

Comment: Just fixed that, @Kamarey. Explicit interface implementation must have no access modifiers, it is always public.

Comment: I get error: `Member 'Foo.Bar()' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead.` when doing `(new Foo()).Bar();` in my app.

Comment: @T.Todua
Yes you need to refer it as an IFoo in order to do that. You can do either `((IFoo)(new Foo())).Bar();` or `IFoo foo = new Foo(); foo.Bar();`

Answer (score 12):

You can call static methods from instance methods without having to specify the type name:

```
class Foo
{
    static void Bar()
    {
    }

    void Fizz()
    {
        Bar();
    }
}
```

... so it makes sense that you wouldn't be allowed to have a static method and an instance method with the same signature.

What are you trying to accomplish? It's hard to suggest a workaround without knowing specifics. I'd just rename one of the methods.

Answer (score 5):

C# is not well designed when it comes to this...

While it is true that you could want the global or non-global, it should pick one by default, and if you want the other then you simply qualify it more.

```
class Logger {
   public static Logger instance;

   public static void Log(string message) {
       instance.Log(message); // currently the compiler thinks this is ambiguous, but really its not at all.  Clearly we want the non-static method
   }

   public void Log(string message) {

   }

   public void DoStuff() {
      Log("doing instance stuff"); // this could be ambiguous, but in my opinion it should default to a call to this.Log()
      Logger.Log("doing global stuff"); // if you want the global qualify it explicitly
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have static and instance method with the same name, as long as their declaration differs in the number or type of parameters. It's the same rule on how you can have two instance methods with the same name in a class.

Though technically, in the case of static vs. instance method, they already differ by the presence of the implicit this parameter in the instance method, that difference is not enough for the compiler to determine which of the two you want to call.

**Update**: I made a mistake. Return values are not enough to have different signature.

Comment: Wrong: as long as their differ in the number and/or type of paramters. Return types don't overload.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using extension methods:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static void DoSomething(int parameter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(parameter.ToString());
    }
}
public static class FooExtensions
{
    public static void DoSomething(this Foo foo, int parameter)
    {
        Foo.DoSomething(parameter);
    }
}
```

It doesn't work if they're not using your namespace that contains your extension methods, but that's always true of extension methods.  So it's not quite perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an optional argument

```
public class Logger
{
    public static Logger logger = new Logger();

    public void Log(string? message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    public void LogStatic(string? message)
    {
        Log(message, null);
    }

    public static void Log(string? message, object? _ = null)
    {
        logger.Log(message);
    }
}
```

.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Logger.logger.Log("...");
    Logger.logger.LogStatic("...");
    Logger.Log("...");
}
```

Comment: While this can technically work thanks to the optional-with-default param, this is quite a hacky solution that can lead to ambiguity (what method really gets called for `Logger.logger.Log("...");` ?) and harder to read code since the actual behavior depends on knowing how the compiler resolves method calls. It is a fairly clever solution but I wouldn't recommend it in production code.