# PHP: Cannot redeclare previously declared function

Tags: php

I am very new to php and I kind of need to work with another person's code. When I try to run it I get this error:

```
Cannot redeclare App\Core\view() (previously declared in 
D:\sandbox\app\Core\View.php:35) in D:\sandbox\app\Core\View.php on line 35
```

While the actual code in D:\sandbox\app\Core\View.php lines 32-50 is:

```
public static function register()
{
    if (!function_exists('view')) {
        function view($view, $data)
        {
            return View::view($view, $data);
        }
    }
}

public static function view($view, $data)
{
    $result = ...;

    return $result;
}
```

There're almost no includes in the project as it seems to be some homemade php framework

Comment: This might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864141/redeclaration-of-instance-and-static-function