# Is access modifier part of Method Signature in C#?

Tags: c#, methods, static, access-modifiers

MSDN here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx says access modifiers like "private/protected" are part of method signature in c#.

However this link below doesnt seem to think so [Method Signature in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808703/method-signature-in-c-sharp)

Which one is it? Also what about a static method? Is the keyword "static" part of method signature?

thanks

Comment: You are mixing what in that page is called *part of the signature of the method for the purposes of method overloading* and the "general" method signature... in that page it is said that the return type isn't part of the "signature for method overloading"... clearly even the `abstract`/`sealed`/`public`/`private` parts aren't part of it.

Comment: thanks. i was keen to understand the "general" method signature guidelines. does "static" form part of method signature?

Comment: I think a good answer to this would clarify what is meant by "method signature", how it is used, and therefore why there might be more than one definition.

Comment: In general, the response of Lipper [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8809191/613130) is good enough for your question (that isn't really a duplicate of the other question... simply put, the answer is good for both)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[C# 5.0 specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029), 1.6.6.Methods:

> The signature of a method consists of the name of the method, the
>   number of type parameters and the number, modifiers, and types of its
>   parameters. The signature of a method does not include the return
>   type.

[CLI specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf), I.8.6.1.5 Method signatures:

- a calling convention*
- the number of generic parameters, if the method is generic,
- if the calling convention specifies this is an instance method and the owning method definition belongs to a type T then the type of the this pointer is ... [irrelevant here]
- a list of zero or more parameter signatures—one for each parameter of the method and,
- a type signature for the result value, if one is produced.

Notes:

* Calling convention includes static/instance specification.

For reference, II.15.3 Calling convention:

> A calling convention specifies how a method expects its arguments to
>   be passed from the caller to the called method. It consists of two
>   parts: **the first deals with the existence and type of the this
>   pointer**, while the second relates to the mechanism for transporting
>   the arguments.

Conclusion: none of the definitions of method signature includes access modifiers.

Comment: But as written here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8809191/613130, *There are two definitions of method signature. The C# language definition* and *The CLR, however, ...*

Comment: @xanatos ok this is interesting spin, I don't think CLR has public specification, so how do we know how CLR defines signature.

Comment: Clearly there is a public specification... there is a whole ECMA standard that describes how an assembly is constructed... ECMA-335

Comment: @xanatos CLR and CLI is not the same though, but yeah this topic is covered extensively in ECMA-335

Comment: so the access modifiers and "static" ARE part of the signature then? according to C#?

Comment: @nesh_s in CLI definition: static - yes, access modifiers - no. In C# definition: no for both.

Answer (score 0):

In don't believe is static is part of the method signature because even though static methods are called:

```
Classname.StaticMethodName(..);
```

While instance methods are called:

```
var o = new Classname();
o.MethodName(..);
```

It still defines methods and parameters that match for the signature.  See this for more on the static vs instance methods and signature: [Static and Instance methods with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160118/static-and-instance-methods-with-the-same-name)

Access level is not part of the signature because you can't have:

```
public void DoThis();

private void DoThis();
```

Both methods have the same signature because signature is based on method, generic parameter(s), and method parameter(s)/types.

The following are valid:

```
public void DoThis();
private void DoThis(int x);
```

OR:

```
public void DoThis();
private int DoThis<int>();
```

Comment: You can't either have `void Method()` and `static void Method()` in same class.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, No. Method signature is determined by its method name and the parameters accepted by it.

Comment: Not exactly true. There are two definitions (CLI and C#) and one includes return type and static modifier other not.