# Method reference static vs non static

Tags: java, static, java-8, method-reference

I've wondered how to distinct between static and non static method references with the same name. In my example I have a class called `StringCollector` that has the following three methods:
`StringCollector append(String string)`
`static StringCollector append(StringCollector stringCollector, String string)`
`StringCollector concat(StringCollector stringCollector)`
Now if I want to use a `Stream<String>` to collect a list of strings I would write something like that:
`Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c").stream()`
`.collect(StringCollector::new, StringCollector::append, StringCollector::concat);`
As we can see the code doesn't compile. I think that's because the compiler can't deside, which method to use because each of them would match the functional. The question is now: Is there any possible way to distinct static method references from instance method references?
(PS: Yes the code compiles if I rename one of the two methods. For each of them.)

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend naming methods the same as your class...

Comment: Also, here is a C# answer, but it closely applies to Java as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160118/static-and-instance-methods-with-the-same-name

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21873829/2711488

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case unbound reference to the instance method `append` has the same arity, argument types and even return value as the reference to the static method `append`, so no, you cannot resolve the disambiguation for method references. If you don't want to rename one of the methods, you should use lambda instead:

```
collect(StringCollector::new, (sb, s) -> sb.append(s), StringCollector::concat);
```

Or if you actually want to use static method:

```
collect(StringCollector::new, (sb, s) -> StringCollector.append(sb, s),
        StringCollector::concat);
```