# c# force call static function with default value instead of non-static

Tags: c#, object, static

I have an object to manage ini files.

I concept this object to bee used in two ways: static and non-static. So I can call `IniFile.Read` directly when I just need a value or I can instantiate `IniFile` Object and do some operations. All non-static functions call static equivalent one, `myIniFile.Read(sectionName, value, defaultValue)` calls `IniFile.Read(iniPath, sectionName, value, defaultValue)`.
`Read()` function has default value for the last parameter.

My problem is when I call `IniFile.Read()` function, compiler doesn't know if I call the static function or the other one. Is there a way to resolve this problem ?

```
public static string ReadValue(string filePath, string section, string key, string defaultValue="")
public string ReadValue(string Section, string Key, string defaultValue="")
```

Comment: Ok, i found the matter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160118/static-and-instance-methods-with-the-same-name) Thanks you all

Answer (score 2):

To call static function :

```
ClassName.Function();
```

for unstatic:

```
ClassName class_name = new ClassName();

class_name.Function();
```

Comment: I know how static/non-static work, if i call IniFile.ReadValue(myPath, mySection, myValue); it should call the static function, but compilator give me the error "An object reference is required for the non-static method ..."

Comment: As @Skogandr says, you would need to instantiate the class, and call it from the instantiated variable.  For example, var iniFile = new InitFile(); iniFile.ReadValue(...

Comment: No because in the case i want to call the static function

Comment: So in your case you call IniFileClass.ReadValue();

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to disambiguate - given that you, by definition, must have a different signature, is to use the named parameters; for example:

```
iniFile.ReadValue(Section: "test", Key: "key");
```

Comment: great idea, nice one

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly prefix the method with the type name, it should invoke the static method; for example:

```
public void InstanceCallSite()
{
    ReadValue("a", "b", "c");
    // or in the general case: someInstance.ReadValue("a", "b", "c");
    Foo.ReadValue("a", "b", "c");
}

public static void StaticCallSite()
{
    ReadValue("a", "b", "c");
}

public static string ReadValue(string filePath, string section, string key, string defaultValue = "")
{
    Console.WriteLine("static");
    return "";
}
public string ReadValue(string Section, string Key, string defaultValue = "")
{
    Console.WriteLine("instance");
    return "";
}
```

The `InstanceCallSite` usage outputs:

```
instance
static
```

Comment: yeah, it should, but compilator tries to use the bad method. And i get compilation error in the other way when i call myIniFile.WriteValue(INI_SECTION_NAME, KEYNAME, myValue, myDefaultValue);
the compilator thinks i use the static function :(

Comment: @oliviersow can you show a minimal example that actually shows that exception? also: what compiler version are you using? the overload resolution code has been improved at multiple points